# Deleting Elements In An Array Only When They Are Next To Each Other

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that is composed of information that looks like the following:

```
['Jay', 'Jay', 'Jay', 'Spiders', 'Dogs', 'Cats', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Dogs', 'Cows', 'Snakes']
```

What I'm trying to do is remove duplicate entries but only if they occur right next to each other.

The correct result should look like the following:

```
['Jay', 'Spiders', 'Dogs', 'Cats', 'John', 'Dogs', 'Cows', 'Snakes']
```

I'm using PHP but any kind of logic would be able to help me out with this problem.

Here is some code I've tried so far:

```
$clean_pull = array();
$counter = 0;
$prev_value = NULL;

foreach($pull_list as $value) {
    if ($counter == 0) {
        $prev_value = $value;
        $clean_pull[] = $value;
    }
    else {
        if ($value != $pre_value) {
            $pre_value = value;
        }
    }
    echo $value . '<br>';
}
```

Francis, when I run the following code:

```
$lastval = end($pull_list);
for ($i=count($pull_list)-2; $i >= 0; $i--){
    $thisval = $pull_list[$i];
    if ($thisval===$lastval) {
        unset($pull_list[$i]);
    }
    $lastval = $thisval;
}
# optional: reindex the array:
array_splice($pull_list, 0, 0);

var_export($pull_list);
```

, I get these results:

```
array ( 0 => 'NJ Lefler', 1 => 'Deadpool', 2 => 'NJ Lefler', 3 => 'Captain Universe: The Hero Who Could Be You', 4 => 'NJ Lefler', 5 => 'The Movement', 6 => 'NJ Lefler', 7 => 'The Dream Merchant', 8 => 'Nolan Lefler', 9 => 'Deadpool', 10 => 'Nolan Lefler', 11 => 'Captain Universe: The Hero Who Could Be You', 12 => 'Nolan Lefler', 13 => 'The Movement', 14 => 'Tom Smith', 15 => 'Deadpool', 16 => 'Tom Smith', 17 => 'Captain Universe: The Hero Who Could Be You', )
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've tried looping through the array using a "prev_value" variable and a counter to keep track of occurrences, but no success as of yet.

Comment: Okay, so those results are wrong. But what did you put in, and why are they wrong?

Comment: Because if a name appears multiple times one next to each other like "Jay, Jay, Jay, Jay" I only want there to be ONE Jay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your approach (a `$prev_value` variable) should work fine and you don't need a counter.

Your use of `$counter` is why your code doesn't work--the first half of the `if` statement is always executed because `$counter` is never incremented; and the second half just compares values. The only thing you need to do is compare the current value with the previous value and include the current value only if it differs (or remove it only if it's the same).

It's much easier to see this algorithm if you use functional reduction.  Here is an example using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$a = array('Jay', 'Jay', 'Jay', 'Spiders', 'Dogs', 'Cats', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Dogs', 'Cows', 'Snakes');

$na = array_reduce($a, function($acc, $item){
    if (end($acc)!==$item) {
        $acc[] = $item;
    }
    return $acc;
}, array());

var_export($na);
```

Note this comparison of `var_export($a)` (your original array) and `var_export($na)` (the result produced by the code):

```
$a = array (            $na = array (    
  0 => 'Jay',             0 => 'Jay',    
  1 => 'Jay',             1 => 'Spiders',
  2 => 'Jay',             2 => 'Dogs',   
  3 => 'Spiders',         3 => 'Cats',   
  4 => 'Dogs',            4 => 'John',   
  5 => 'Cats',            5 => 'Dogs',   
  6 => 'John',            6 => 'Cows',   
  7 => 'John',            7 => 'Snakes', 
  8 => 'John',          )                
  9 => 'Dogs',
  10 => 'Cows',
  11 => 'Snakes',
)
```

The `array_reduce()` method does exactly the same thing as the following code:

```
$na = array();
foreach ($a as $item) {
    if (end($na)!==$item) {
        $na[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Instead of returning a *copy* of an array, you can also modify the array *in-place* using the same algorithm but starting from the *end* of the array:

```
$lastval = end($a);
for ($i=count($a)-2; $i >= 0; $i--){
    $thisval = $a[$i];
    if ($thisval===$lastval) {
        unset($a[$i]);
    }
    $lastval = $thisval;
}
# optional: reindex the array:
array_splice($a, 0, 0);

var_export($a);
```

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear initially. I have modified the desired results.

Comment: All of this code produces your desired results--I understood the question.

Comment: I will show you the code that is getting returned to me. I am not getting the results I am seeking.

Comment: @JimRomeFan This code producing the same result as you desire.

Comment: @JimRomeFan, make sure you are not being confused by how the array is *printed* (with `var_dump` or `var_export`) vs its actual *value*. The *value* you desire is correct; how it's printed may not be, but that is not really part of your question.

Comment: @JimRomeFan, I have added a side-by-side comparison of `$a` and `$na`. This is almost certainly the result you want.

Comment: I found my mistake. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of the last element in the array, and skip adding the next element to your new array if you just added it.

Or, you can just check the last element in the array, and see if it's not the current element in your array:

```
$array = ['Jay', 'Jay', 'Jay', 'Spiders', 'Dogs', 'Cats', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Dogs', 'Cows', 'Snakes'];
$new = array( array_shift( $array));
foreach( $array as $el) {
    if( !($new[count($new) - 1] === $el)) {
        $new[] = $el;
    }
}
```

Comment: Like the `array_reduce` thing above, except waay more sensical :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array isn't so large that having a second one will cause a problem, the approach you described [should work](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LMhuuu). Does it look like this?

```
$last = null;
$result = [];

foreach($arr as $item)
    if($item !== $last)
        $result[] = $last = $item;
```

---

Re: edit:

- `$pre_value` and `$prev_value` aren't the same thing
- `$counter` doesn't change

It looks like you tried to combine a counter approach and a "last" approach somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable `glob`.
pass the array:
`if (array[i] == glob) then
      remove array[i]`
`else 
      glob = array[i];
      keep array[i];`